# Issue with OneNote permissions

Tags: c#, ms-office, onenote, onenote-api

I'm trying to create a sample app which can get and post new pages from my one note account.

I'm following this guide:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-auth

I was correctly able to get the access token through the microsoft account, but every call to the OneNote apis fails with a 401 error.

I'm working in c# and using the HttpWebRequest to perform the calls.

My suspects are related to the permissions which I wasn't able to set:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-auth#onenote-perms-msa

How can I set those permissions?

Thanks everybody for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which Scopes are you setting? Scopes (or permissions) are ser via a query parameter when redirecting the user to the sign in page. For creating a page you'll need at least office.onenote_create.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn807159.aspx

Depending on whether you're working on a webpage or a windows app, we have plenty of samples to look at.

For client side (C#)
https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleWinUniversal
https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleWinStore

For server side (we don't have. C# sample yet)
https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleNodejs